# how to check dynamically created check box status

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
I had created dynamic checkboxes and added them to the table on asp.net


Here is my code:
**Creating checkbox:**

                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                TableRow tr;
    // maintaining only 3 cells per row
                    if (num3 % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        tr = new TableRow();
                        tblImage.Rows.Add(tr);
                    }
                    else
                        tr = tblImage.Rows[num3 / 3];

                    // creating checkbox
                    cb.ID = "cb" + (num3 + 1);
                    cb.Text = "Page " + (num3 + 1);
    // adding to table cell
                    tc.Controls.Add(cb);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```

Now, On a button click event (server side), I want to get the checkbox id's where the  checkbox is checked how to do it?

```
**Button Click Event:**
```

In this event, I'm getting the rows count as zero always. Not sure of the reason. Even though it has 2 rows & 6 cells in total.

```
            //getting rows count to check
            int cnt = tblImage.Rows.Count; 
    // Always getting zero, even though there are 2 rows
            //looping through each row
            foreach (TableRow tr in tblImage.Rows)
            {
//looping through each cell
             foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
             {
// looping for controls
              foreach (Control ctr in tc.Controls)
              {
// checking for a checkbox
                var cb = ctr as CheckBox;

                if (cb != null)
                {
        //getting check box id & status
                 Response.Write(cb.ID+" State: "+cb.Checked+"<br/>");
                }
               }
              }
            }

In this button click event, the table rows count is always showing as 0.
```

Comment: You need to recreate the dynamic controls on every page load, and that includes a PostBack otherwise the controls are lost and you cannot get their values (or row count).

Comment: Thank you VDWWD...

Answer (score -1):

```
 foreach(Control ctrl in tc.Controls)
  {
       if(ctrl is CheckBox)
       {
           CheckBox chkBox= ctrl as CheckBox ; 
           if(chkBox.Checked == true)
               // do something.
       }
  }
```

Comment: It's not at all coming in to the loop, in Tablerow itself, the event was completing.

Comment: While this [code may answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.